# Text editor supports snippets inside snippets without breaking cursor next position

Tags: text, editor, atom-editor, code-snippets

I'm using Atom to write LaTeX and C++. When I use for example a snippet:

Prefix 'fr' expands to '\frac{$1}{$2} $3' meaning that typing 'f r TAB' creates the sentence '/frac{}{}' and places the cursor at position '$1', pressing TAB again moves the cursor to '$2', TAB again moves the cursor outside of the expression in position '$3'.

However, support that I have a snippet 'sq' which expands to '\sqrt($1)'. This means that typing 's q TAB' creates the text '\sqrt()' and places the cursor in position '$1'.

Now suppose I want to combine both snippets.

'f r TAB' expands to '\frac{$1}{$2}', I then type '2' to insert the number '2' in the position of '$1', I press TAB to jump to position '$2' and now I want to insert 'sqrt(2)'. Then I type 's q TAB' and it expands to the following total expression:

'\frac{2}{sqrt($1)}'

The cursor is in '$1' I then type '2' and the expression now is:

'\frac{2}{sqrt(2)}'

Now if I press TAB again it will indent right after 2, like this:

'\frac{2}{sqrt(2...........)}'

What I would like it to do is go to the next position of '\frac{$1}{$2} $3', that is, position '$3' outside of the frac expression so I can continue typing without having to press right arrow, right arrow, etc.

Is there any text editor that can do this, even if it uses plugins to achieve it? It would be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

They're only recursice on their last field https://discuss.atom.io/t/recursive-snippets/44160

Answer (score 0):

If anyone run into the same problem. Emacs with yasnippets did it for me. Adding this line to .emacs:

(setq yas-triggers-in-field t)

It supports nested snippets and you can jump through placeholders of the current snippet and the past one.